# ActionScript3 Function to hide or show movieclip currently on stage in a different class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Hello lovely Actionscript peoples. I am having a bit of a problem creating a button using AS3 that can hide or show a specific movieclip that is being called by a different class. I think, honestly, that my problem is that I don't fundamentally understand OOP / classes as they are utilized in AS3, however I will post my understanding of the problem here -

1. I have 3 different classes, `ConsStartMenu.as` (document class), Menu.as (the menu that I want to hide and show), and `SideMenu.as` (contains the button that I want to hit to hide / show the menu). I am calling the display of my Menu and SideMenu MovieClips from `ConsStartMenu.as`. Relevant code here -

   ```
   public var menuDisplay:Menu = new Menu();
   public var sidemenuDisplay:SideMenu = new SideMenu();

   public function ConsStartMenu():void  {
       stage.addChild(menuDisplay);
       menuDisplay.x=stage.stageWidth * .5;
       menuDisplay.y=stage.stageHeight * .5;
       stage.addChild(sidemenuDisplay);
       sidemenuDisplay.x=stage.stageWidth*.98;
       sidemenuDisplay.y=stage.stageHeight*.5;
   }
   ```
2. Within my `SideMenu.as`, I have this code to reference the Menu that I think? is on the stage -

   ```
   public var centerMenu:Menu = new Menu();
   ```

and then on the actions of the frame that the button is on I have -

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

OpenSideMenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, LinkOpenSideMenu);

function LinkOpenSideMenu(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if (centerMenu.parent.stage){
        trace ("center Menu is in display list");
        centerMenu.parent.removeChild(centerMenu);
    }
    else
    {
        trace("Adding menu back to stage");
        centerMenu.parent.addChild(centerMenu);
    }
}
```

When I click the button I get this error from it -

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at SideMenu/LinkOpenSideMenu()[SideMenu::frame1:9]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which line of code is `SideMenu->Frame 1-> Line 9`?

Comment: Seems to be the first time I call centerMenu -
if (centerMenu.parent.stage)

Comment: It's likely the parent property of centerMenu that is null/undefined. If centerMenu is not added to the display list, it's parent is not going to be defined and you cannot try to access its stage property.

Comment: Sorry to ask this so directly, as I am a bit new to this. I am attempting to hide and show a movieclip called Menu, which is being called to the stage by ConsStartMenu.as. Which of these 2 things would I need to do in SideMenu.as - 

1. public var centerMenu:Menu = new Menu();
or
2. public var centerMenu:ConsStartMenu = new ConsStartMenu();

Comment: The `stage` property is not available in your classes constructor (because it hasn't been added to anything yet at that point) - when you do this: `public function ConsStartMenu():void  {
    stage.addChild(menuDisplay);`  Stage will be null

Comment: So stage is just a variable that I created at that point? It's not defined within AS as something that I reference?

Comment: It's managed by AS3 automatically, but there is no guarantee it will be populated yet in your constructor of your document class, and it will for certain be null in your other constructors. Same with `parent`

Comment: Ok. So what would I add to "populate" it? Just define it as a variable? public var stage:Object;?

Comment: Are you ever adding `centerMenu` to the stage?  You instantiate it by doing: `public var centerMenu:Menu = new Menu();`  but you also need to add it `addChild(centerMenu);` before it will have a value in it's `stage` and `parent` properties

Comment: No, that's not what I'm trying to do. Let me try this all over again, as I clearly haven't explained it well.

1. On ConsStartMenu.as, I call to the stage, a movieclip contained with Menu. I give it the variable name menuDisplay, and call it to the stage with the line addChild(menuDisplay). 

2. In SideMenu.as, I am trying to create a button that can hide or show menuDisplay from ConsStartMenu. I thought that I had to give it another variable name, such as centerMenu, so that's what I did.

Comment: My guess, is that you don't want two different versions of the `Menu` class, but that you want a reference in `SideMenu` to the one you created in `ConStartMenu`

Comment: Yes, that sounds very right. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is confusion between object references and instantiation.

When you use the `new` keyword, you are creating a whole new object.

So in `ConStartMenu` when you do this:

```
public var menuDisplay:Menu = new Menu();
```

You are creating a new `Menu` object.

And, in `SideMenu` when you do this:

```
public var centerMenu:Menu = new Menu();
```

You are creating a second `Menu` object (that has nothing to do with the first).

What you want, is a reference to that first menu created.

There are a few ways you can do this:

1. Pass the reference in to the constructor of `SideMenu`.

   ```
   public var menuDisplay:Menu;
   public var sidemenuDisplay:SideMenu;

   public function ConsStartMenu():void  {
       menuDisplay = new Menu();
       sidemenuDisplay:SideMenu = new SideMenu(menuDisplay);
       //...rest of code
   ```

---

```
    //then in your side menu class:

    public var centerMenu:Menu;
    public function SideMenu(menu:Menu){
        centerMenu = menu;
        //now you have a reference to the menu
    }
```

2. Make the `menuDisplay` var in `ConStartMenu` `static`. (Static variables are accessable through the class itself and are not a part of instantiation

   ```
   public static var menuDisplay:Menu = new Menu();

   //now you can access it anywhere in your app by doing:
   ConStartMenu.menuDisplay
   ```
3. Use parentage to find it.  Since your `ConStartMenu` instance is the parent of your `SideMenu`, you can access any public methods/var of `ConStartMenu` using the parent keyword:

   ```
   //from within SideMenu
   parent.menuDisplay;

   //or, to avoid a warning, tell the compiler that parent is of type ConStartMenu (cast)
   ConStartMenu(parent).menuDisplay
   ```

Comment: Ok. This is a good explanation, however doesn't seem to work with my set up. When I add this into SideMenu 

 public class SideMenu extends MovieClip {
    
   
  public var sidemenuDisplay:SideMenu = new SideMenu(menuDisplay);

I get 4 errors on that line - 

2 x 1137: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected no more than 0.
2 x 1120: Access of undefined property menuDisplay.

I know that this is just 100% because I don't understand AS3, so I think you for your patience with me on this. It's tremendously confusing.

Comment: It's best if you instantiate complex objects inside the constructor, not where you define the var (to avoid this problem).  I'll updated with an example. The incorrect arguments error means that you did you updated the contructor of your `SideMenu` class to receive that extra parameter

Comment: Ok. I've decided to go with option 2, as it makes the most sense to me, and honestly the way that I wish the entirety of AS would work, at least in my head. So close to a solution now, I can feel it. 
It seems like my button can now see menuDisplay, but can't do anything to it. Here's the new code and the error - 

ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
 at SideMenu/LinkOpenSideMenu()[SideMenu::frame1:12]

Comment: function LinkOpenSideMenu(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
   if (ConsStartMenu.menuDisplay.stage)
   {
    trace ("center Menu is in display list");
    removeChild(ConsStartMenu.menuDisplay);
    
   }
   else
   {
    trace("Adding menu back to stage");
    addChild(ConsStartMenu.menuDisplay);
   }
  }

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting - is there any way to put that in a more readable state?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Thank you so much for your help! Here was the final code - turns out I was trying to remove it from stage, instead of just making it visible vs not visible. Thank you SO much!!

function LinkOpenSideMenu(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
   if (ConsStartMenu.menuDisplay.visible)
   {
    ConsStartMenu.menuDisplay.visible = false;
   }
   else
   {
    ConsStartMenu.menuDisplay.visible = true;
   }
  }

Comment: When you do `removeChild`, it's trying to remove it from whatever object your in (which isn't the parent, `stage` is if that's what you added it to).  The safest way to remove something is `child.parent.removeChild(child)`.    Glad you got it figured out